# Extra memory allocations when aliasing a tuple type

Tags: julia

With Julia 1.5.3, I have the following code (of course it's not actual code, just a contrived example with which I could repro the problem):

```julia
function basic()
    result::Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64} = (0, 0, 0)
    for i in 1:100000
        for i in -1:1, j in -1:1, k in -1:1
            result = result .+ (i, j, k)
        end
    end
    result
end

function fancy(T)
    result::T = (0, 0, 0)
    for i in 1:100000
        for i in -1:1, j in -1:1, k in -1:1
            result = result .+ (i, j, k)::T
        end
    end
    result
end

# Warmup
for i in 1:10
    basic()
    fancy(Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64})
end

println("basic:")
println(@time basic())
println("fancy:")
println(@time fancy(Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64}))
```

outputs:

```
basic:
  0.000000 seconds
(0, 0, 0)
fancy:
  0.762599 seconds (10.80 M allocations: 494.385 MiB, 3.68% gc time)
(0, 0, 0)
```

If I write instead:

```julia
            result = result .+ (i, j, k)::T
```

I get:

```
basic:
  0.000000 seconds
(0, 0, 0)
fancy:
  0.789512 seconds (13.50 M allocations: 576.782 MiB, 3.77% gc time)
(0, 0, 0)
```

Is there a way to make `basic` and `fancy` perform the same, i.e. without allocations in `fancy`?

Comment: You might also consider using an `SVector` from `StaticArrays` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Just change the signature of `fancy`:

```
function fancy(::Type{T}) where T
    result::T = (0, 0, 0)
    for i in 1:100000
        for i in -1:1, j in -1:1, k in -1:1
            result = result .+ (i, j, k)::T
        end
    end
    result
end

println(@time fancy(Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64}))
```

Just note that both functions actually optimized to almost-no-op. You can inspect it with `@code_native basic()`.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. Just to be sure, `fancy(::Type{T}) where T` means that we accept a parameter that is a type and that type is parametrized to be T.

So now I'm curious what the code did in my question:

`function fancy(T) result::T = (0, 0, 0) ...`

What was T then?

Comment: Duh, in my question `T` was a parameter of type `Any`. But then what did `result::T` mean? I guess that was a dynamic type check at assignment time?

Comment: Yes. Actually it is more like `result = convert(T, (0,0,0))` than a type assert.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
function fancy(T)
    result = T((0, 0, 0))
    for i in 1:100000
        for i in -1:1, j in -1:1, k in -1:1
            result = result .+ T((i, j, k))
        end
    end
    result
end
```